# JSON pretty printing isn't working in Python

Tags: python, json

As far as I can tell, this code should work.

```
import json
with open('path', 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

But it doesn't. I get this:

```
"b'{\"Markets\":[{\"ID\":2461,\"Name\":\"Who will be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Who will be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Markets/5914fd50-9a60-46d1-ac5f-b36c2c4c9832.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Market/2461/Who-will-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Contracts\":[{\"ID\":3613,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_494e673d-12cc-40c5-ab6a-2976c582303f.png\" ...
```

However, if I go to http://jsonprettyprint.com/ and give it the same data, I get pretty indentation. So the problem's with the code, not the data (though I don't understand why there are so many backslashes).

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sample data

```
"b'{\"ID\":2461,\"Name\":\"Who will be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Who will be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Markets/5914fd50-9a60-46d1-ac5f-b36c2c4c9832.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Market/2461/Who-will-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Contracts\":[{\"ID\":3613,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_494e673d-12cc-40c5-ab6a-2976c582303f.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3613/Will-Angela-Merkel-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Angela Merkel\",\"LongName\":\"Will Angela Merkel be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Merkel\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"MERKEL.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.10,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.10,\"BestBuyNoCost\":0.93,\"BestSellYesCost\":0.07,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.90,\"LastClosePrice\":0.10},{\"ID\":3614,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_d87c6a74-372d-40b5-95d9-2f994738acf5.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3614/Will-Sigmar-Gabriel-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Sigmar Gabriel\",\"LongName\":\"Will Sigmar Gabriel be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Gabriel\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"GABRIEL.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3615,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_be043f00-72fb-479c-b5ae-37e51154935f.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3615/Will-Frank-Walter-Steinmeier-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Frank-Walter Steinmeier\",\"LongName\":\"Will Frank-Walter Steinmeier be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Steinmeier\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"STEINMEIER.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3616,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_9d6f499c-245d-4cba-a1b1-537d1a41408d.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3616/Will-Martin-Schulz-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Martin Schulz\",\"LongName\":\"Will Martin Schulz be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Schulz\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"SCHULZ.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3617,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_a8e62e71-b5f3-4050-8340-c41204d58e30.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3617/Will-Wolfgang-Sch%C3%A4uble-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Wolfgang Sch\\xc3\\xa4uble\",\"LongName\":\"Will Wolfgang Sch\\xc3\\xa4uble be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Sch\\xc3\\xa4uble\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"SCHAUBLE.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3618,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_a41f6020-3a21-4679-ab04-1ff2c4e90e14.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3618/Will-Frauke-Petry-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Frauke Petry\",\"LongName\":\"Will Frauke Petry be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Petry\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"PETRY.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3619,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_18819f42-5bba-4640-96fb-e62ce4879cd0.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3619/Will-Thomas-de-Maizi%C3%A8re-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Thomas de Maizi\\xc3\\xa8re\",\"LongName\":\"Will Thomas de Maizi\\xc3\\xa8re be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"de Maizi\\xc3\\xa8re\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"DEMAIZIERE.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3620,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_deffbe18-669e-45c6-9bb5-62ab61363d49.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3620/Will-Ursula-Von-der-Leyen-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Ursula Von der Leyen\",\"LongName\":\"Will Ursula Von der Leyen be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Von der Leyen\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"VONDERLEYEN.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3621,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_0b630af8-c76c-427c-91af-50a2e5f37bc4.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3621/Will-Christian-Lindner-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Christian Lindner\",\"LongName\":\"Will Christian Lindner be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Lindner\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"LINDNER.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3622,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_e6aaf4d2-00c7-437c-82c0-d29336d75ad7.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3622/Will-Horst-Seehofer-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Horst Seehofer\",\"LongName\":\"Will Horst Seehofer be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Seehofer\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"SEEHOFER.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3623,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_59a0cbcf-8bbf-4f39-ab30-175d9213732f.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3623/Will-Cem-%C3%96zdemir-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Cem \\xc3\\x96zdemir\",\"LongName\":\"Will Cem \\xc3\\x96zdemir be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"\\xc3\\x96zdemir\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"OZDEMIR.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3624,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_076c33fc-39fc-414f-abf2-cc7dfa2e4dad.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3624/Will-Katja-Kipping-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Katja Kipping\",\"LongName\":\"Will Katja Kipping be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Kipping\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"KIPPING.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3625,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_84a1659d-63fd-4169-a5e7-49762df694e2.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3625/Will-Hannelore-Kraft-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Hannelore Kraft\",\"LongName\":\"Will Hannelore Kraft be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Kraft\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"KRAFT.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3626,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_80d9880b-1881-4079-9935-c0a5691876e9.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3626/Will-Peter-Altmaier-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Peter Altmaier\",\"LongName\":\"Will Peter Altmaier be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Altmaier\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"ALTMAIER.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":3627,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_cb11286d-c0b9-41fc-a4b0-3f52dccbd9bf.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/3627/Will-Olaf-Scholz-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Olaf Scholz\",\"LongName\":\"Will Olaf Scholz be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Scholz\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"SCHOLZ.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":4866,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_72649d7f-0d79-4d34-a061-3920669d69c3.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/4866/Will-Jens-Spahn-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Jens Spahn\",\"LongName\":\"Will Jens Spahn be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Spahn\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"SPAHN.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":4885,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_86dc58ff-2801-4174-acb6-3fea5f5b801f.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/4885/Will-Leif-Erik-Holm-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Leif-Erik Holm\",\"LongName\":\"Will Leif-Erik Holm be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Holm\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"HOLM.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":4920,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_bc912c09-4d05-4d0a-9bba-d2dda6621b5d.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/4920/Will-Karl-Theodor-zu-Guttenberg-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Karl-Theodor zu Guttenberg\",\"LongName\":\"Will Karl-Theodor zu Guttenberg be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Guttenberg\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"GUTTENBERG.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.02,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.98,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":7974,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_a2440597-a99e-4ab3-96cc-0c821bb978a0.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/7974/Will-Alexander-Gauland-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Alexander Gauland\",\"LongName\":\"Will Alexander Gauland be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Gauland\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"GAUL.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01},{\"ID\":7975,\"DateEnd\":\"N/A\",\"Image\":\"https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_9bec806a-8b80-47e2-bd03-c279a2b6b799.png\",\"URL\":\"https://www.predictit.org/Contract/7975/Will-Alice-Weidel-be-elected-German-chancellor-in-2017\",\"Name\":\"Alice Weidel\",\"LongName\":\"Will Alice Weidel be elected German chancellor in 2017?\",\"ShortName\":\"Weidel\",\"TickerSymbol\":\"WEID.CHANCELLOR.GERMANY.2017\",\"Status\":\"Open\",\"LastTradePrice\":0.01,\"BestBuyYesCost\":0.01,\"BestBuyNoCost\":null,\"BestSellYesCost\":null,\"BestSellNoCost\":0.99,\"LastClosePrice\":0.01}],\"TimeStamp\":\"2017-12-09T01:44:29.7878389\",\"Status\":\"Open\"}'"
```

Edit 2: The admittedly messy code to produce the json file.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

q = Request('https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/')
q.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')

import json
import datetime

def saveData(data):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    path = 'json/PI ' + str(now) + '.json'
    path = path.replace(':','-') # No colons in file name
    with open(path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(str(data), outfile, ensure_ascii=False)

import time
starttime=time.time()
while True:
    data = urlopen(q).read()
    saveData(data)
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: can you post the entire data

Comment: It's 639KB of data.

Comment: Here you go: https://ufile.io/k0usp

Comment: Maybe you can come up with some example data, with which we could reproduce the problem, that is *less than* 639KB?

Comment: Yes exactly as what @ChrisMartin said

Comment: 13KB is as small as I can go. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you produce this file? It's not a JSON object, it's a *JSON string* containing a *Python repr* containing a string of your original JSON. Or something like that. Which you can tell because of all the extra backslashes and the leading `b'` character.

This works:

```
import json
from ast import literal_eval

file_data = open('test_file.json', 'r').read()
python_repr = json.loads(file_data)
json_string = literal_eval(python_repr)
actual_dict = json.loads(json_string.decode('utf-8'))
print(json.dumps(actual_dict, indent=4)) # finally.
```

But how in tarnation did you manage this in the first place?

You can write it back as simple JSON instead of multi-encoded wtf too:

```
with open('output.json', 'wb') as out_file:
    json.dump(actual_dict, out_file, indent=4)
```

EDIT for file write:

When you read the data from the website, it's a string containing the JSON object. You need to convert that into a Python `dict` first, *then* write it out. **Without** calling `str` on it again. That's how you're ending up with the triple-encoded mess. Using your code from above:

```
data = urlopen(q).read()
json_data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8')) # DECODE THE STRING 
with open('output.json', 'w') as out:
    json.dump(json_data, out, indent=4) # DO NOT CALL STR ON IT AGAIN
```

Once you've written it cleanly, you can read it easily too:

```
json_loaded = json.load(open('output.json', 'r'))
```

Which will load it up as a python dict.

I'd suggest learning a bit more about the difference between your data itself and various representations of that data.

EDIT2: Also note that if you just want to save the data, you can simply write what you're getting from the website directly into a file, without bothering with the `json.load/dump` roundtrip.

```
data = urlopen(q).read()
with open('output.json', 'w') as out:
    out.write(data)
```

Comment: I got it from a website's API. See Edit 2.

Comment: But yeah, ultimately the source data should be correct. Not sure how I'm storing it incorrectly. Maybe I can ask about that in a separate post.

Comment: @nimbus7 you're starting with a string, not decoding it into a dict, and then calling `str` on it _again_ which is how you're ending up with that mess. See my edit for a clean way to write the data you're getting.

Comment: I'm new to python, so I'm not surprised that I made this mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @nimbus7 You're welcome! Also see my second edit - you should probably just save the data from the API directly into the file, there's no need to actually parse the JSON inside your loop unless you need to do other things with it as well. It will load correctly.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and everything is working as it should. Much appreciated!

Comment: It also got the file size down to 615KB. ;)